# Can I override equals() to count comparisons during hashing?

Tags: java, collections, hashtable

Have created two custom classes say A and B, where A is defined by a pair of integers and B defined by an array of type A (B is an array of integer pairs). I'm trying to store a large quantity of B objects in a hashtable using the first pair in B's array as the Hashing key. I've overridden the hashCode for both classes, and in overriding A's equals() method I'm trying to increment a comparison counter like so:

```
public boolean equals(Object b)
{
  comparisons++; //predefined as a field of A 
  return int1==((A)b).int1 && int2==((A)b).int2;
}
```

However, while I believe this code makes sense, using it like this in main:

```
B b = new B(pairsOfA);
key = b.pairs[0]; //use first pair as key for hash table
hTable.put(key, b);
comparisons = comparisons + hTable.get(key).pairs[0].comparisons;
```

Only gets me the number of comparisons used in the get method, since each table member is only compared to once during searching I'm assuming. Is there a way to count comparisons during hashing with overriding hashTable.put()?

Comment: As a sidenote, if you didn´t do so yet, you should also check the class of `b` in your equals method, otherwhise you might end up with a classcastexception or a nullpointerexception anywhere.

Comment: You *are* counting calls to `equals()` during `put()` calls, but if the hash value resolves to an empty bucket, there are no objects to compare with, so no calls to `equals()`. How often buckets are empty depends on how good the hash function is and the load factor (default is `0.75` on [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28%29)).

Comment: I don't think that's the (only) problem @Andreas, because in retrieving the stored object by using get(), it sets comparisons to 1 for each retrieval and my total number of comparisons always ends up equal to the input. But I don't know how else to access the object in the table without using get() on it.

Comment: I don't know what you are expecting, because a perfectly-distributed hash will have at most 1 object per bucket, and inserting a new key into an empty bucket will require no compares, and retrieving an object will require 1 compare to check if the key found in the bucket is the right one. What you are seeing is exactly what you'd expect. If you *want* to see bucket clashes, set a higher load factor and make sure to fill the initial capacity.

Comment: We're supposed to count the number of comparisons needed to add N objects to an appropriately sized hash table. I don't really understand the built in functionality of hashTable enough to understand what's being compared to what though.